Is there a way to disable SwiftUI search bar without opting for UINavigationController?
I'm trying to disable the .searchable when the screen is in edit mode (similar to Notes). I found out that it's not possible to disable the search bar with SwiftUI. UIKit has a .userInteractionEnabled property that you can apply to a UISearchBar for desired results. My question is would it be possible to disable a search bar without using UINavigationController? If so, could you provide an example of how?
Please note that the question is not about conditionally toggling the search bar. It is about making the bar inactive. Similar to this question, but for SwiftUI world.

